# Botão de navegabilidade não funciona no Angular

Tags: css, angular

Observem bem a imagem abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse teste logo acima foi realizado num arquivo [HTML](https://github.com/wladyband/parallax) com CSS, e está funcionando perfeitamente, porém fiz o mesmo teste num projeto Angular com o mesmo código e não funcionou corretamente, o que acontece é que o menu com o sinal de (Mais) aparece em tela, porém o menu que fica escondido não aparece, é o mesmo código e não entendo porque não funciona;

Eu coloquei a importação do Javascript no arquivo principal do Angular no index.html, ele ficou assim;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AlgamoneyUi</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
<script src="assets/script/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Esse é o arquivo **app.component.html**

```
<header>
    <h1>Estrutura One Page</h1>
</header>

<main>
    <nav>
        <div class="menu"><i class="material-icons">&#xE145;</i></div>
        <div class="nav-itens">
            <a href="#topo" class="tooltip"  data-tooltip="Topo fixo">
                <i class="material-icons">&#xE30C;</i>
                <label class="text_tooltip"></label>
            </a>
            <a href="#botao" class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Botões">
                <i class="material-icons">&#xE30F;</i>
                <label class="text_tooltip"></label>
            </a>
            <a href="#tolltips" class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Tooltips">
                <i class="material-icons">&#xE0CB;</i>
                <label class="text_tooltip"></label>
            </a>
            <a href="#parallax" class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Parallax">
                <i class="material-icons">&#xE6DD;</i>
                <label class="text_tooltip"></label>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <div id="topo" class="section_info">
            <div class="row container">
                <h2 class="header">Topo Fixo</h2>
                <p>O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressсo. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="parallax-container">
            <div class="parallax"><img src="img/imagem1.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div id="botao" class="section_info">
            <div class="row container">
                <h2 class="header">Botões de navegação</h2>
                <p>É um facto estabelecido de que um leitor é distraído pelo conteúdo legível de uma página quando analisa a sua mancha gráfica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribuição mais ou menos normal de letras, ao contrário do uso de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui", tornando-o texto legível. Muitas ferramentas de publicação electrónica e editores de páginas web usam actualmente o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omissсo, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" irá encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua infáncia. Várias versões tem evoluído ao longo dos anos, por vezes por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="parallax-container">
            <div class="parallax"><img src="img/imagem2.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div id="tolltips" class="section_info">
            <div class="row container">
                <h2 class="header">Tooltips</h2>
                <p>Existem muitas variações das passagens modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressсo. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="parallax-container">
            <div class="parallax"><img src="img/imagem3.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div id="parallax" class="section_info">
            <div class="row container">
                <h2 class="header">Parallax</h2>
                <p>Existem muitas variações das passagens do Lorem Ipsum disponíveis, mas a maior parte sofreu alterações de alguma forma, pela injecção de humor, ou de palavras aleatórias que nem sequer parecem suficientemente credíveis. Se vai usar uma passagem do Lorem Ipsum, deve ter a certeza que não contém nada de embaraуoso escondido no meio do texto. Todos os geradores de Lorem Ipsum na Internet acabam por repetir texto pré-definido, como necessário, fazendo com que este seja o primeiro verdadeiro gerador na Internet. Usa um dicionário de 200 palavras em Latim, combinado com uma dúzia de modelos de frases, para gerar Lorem Ipsum que pareуam razoáveis. Desta forma, o Lorem Ipsum gerado é sempre livre de repetição, ou de injecção humorística, etc.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <p>CURSO DEVMEDIA</p>
</footer>
```

Esse é o Javascript;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("nav").mouseover(function(){
        $(".nav-itens").addClass("nav-show");          
    });
    $("nav").mouseout(function(){
        $(".nav-itens").removeClass("nav-show");        
    });


    var page = $('html, body');
    $('a.tooltip').click(function() {
    page.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
    });

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var topWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(topWindow > 60) {
           $("header").addClass('header_fixed');
        }else {
           $("header").removeClass('header_fixed');
        };
    });
});
```

Alguém consegue identificar o problema?

Comment: (1) Seus imports de style e js ficam melhores se realizados dentro do angular.json ou angular-cli.json isso depende de qual versão vocês está do angular-cli. Acredito que isso ajude nessa parte [como por css e js no angular-cli](https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3)

 (2) Você esta usando jquery? Não vejo o importe do mesmo, talvez seja por isso que não está funcionando. Aconselho utilizar o gerenciador de pacote npm para essas instalações, caso você não esteja usando ainda.

Comment: você  tinha razão, realmente tinha erros nos console do navegador e faltava os imports do Jquery, mas eu coloquei as impportações necessárias que estava faltando, e agora não está gerando mais erros no console do MSDOS onde executo o `ng server` e não está gerando mais erros no console do navegador, porém ainda continua sem funcionar.

Comment: eu importei a forma correta os arquivos javascript, se tiver dúvida está aqui meu projeto no repositório do Github https://github.com/wladyband/blog/blob/master/src/index.html

Comment: @jcebidanes esse os testes colocando no arquivo angular-cli , porém também não funcionou.

Comment: Coloca o codigo JQuery dentro de um NgOnInit no component onde vc chama esse botao (mais).